# I am not able to install packages for SharePoint 2013 February 2016 CU on my Windows Server

Tags: sharepoint-2013, failed-installation, sharepoint-upgrade

I have upgraded my SharePoint 2013 Server to SP1. That is, my current build number is 15.0.4571.1502. And I want version 15.0.4797.1001 (that is, SharePoint Server 2013 February 2016 CU).

But when i try to run the setup file (ubersrv2013-kb3114726-fullfile-x64-glb.exe), the installation fails. I get message that "The installation of this package failed.."

Can anyone tell me the reason why ?

Comment: From the MS Support link the below is given:This security update resolves vulnerabilities in Microsoft Office that could allow remote code execution if a user opens a specially crafted Office file. To learn more about these vulnerabilities, see Microsoft Security Bulletin MS16-015.

Note To apply this security update, you must have the release version of Service Pack 1 for Microsoft Office Web Apps Server 2013 installed on the computer.

For a complete list of affected versions of Microsoft Office software, see Microsoft Knowledge Base article 3134226.

Comment: @imSantoshKumar I don't think your comment was correct. In my case the root cause was that the .exe installer was expecting extra files to be in the same directory.

Answer (score 2):

There are three files associated with this update:

- ubersrv_1.cab
- ubersrv_2.cab
- ubersrv2013-kb3114726-fullfile-x64-glb.exe

You might think, as I did, that only the .exe file is required. It and ubersrv_1.cab are both 1.4GB in size after all. It turns out you need all three files in the same directory. I suspect this a bug in the .exe file. Take a look at `%tmp\opatchinstall(1).log`, and search for "OPatchInstall: Thrown CDetectionExceptionWin32(2)". This is basically a "file not found" error, and the line above it will reference one of the .cab files.